# Функция universalMax

Tags: c, алгоритм, функции

Предо мною поставлена такая интересная задача. Нужно написать функцию `universalMax`, которая находит и возвращает индекс максимального элемента для массива любого типа.

Прототип функции:

```
int universalMax(void array, int array_len, int size_of_elements, int(*pcompare)(const void*, const void*));
```

Типы данных:
`char`, `int`, `double`.

То есть я передаю данной функции массив символов или цифр, и она возвращает индекс максимального элемента.

Но у меня такой вопрос, что такое `void array`?

Comment: "И как мне считать данные с потока и записать в массив" - почему этот вообще никак не относящийся к теме вопрос прилеплен сюда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `void` является неполным типом и не имеет значений. Правильно будет объявить первый параметр, как имеющий тип указателя `const void *`

К тому же будет неправильно использовать тип `int` для количества элементов в массиве, так как в общем случае число элементов в массиве может иметь значение, которое не умещается в объекте типа `int`. По крайней мере вам следовало объявить соответствующий параметр, как имеющий тип `ptrdiff_t`. Однако более предпочтительно объявить его, как имеюший тип `size_t`, как это имеет место в объявлениях стандартных C функций.

Функция может быть определена, как это показано ниже в демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t universalMax( const void *a, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int cmp(const void *, const void *) )
{
    size_t max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < nmemb; i++ )
    {
        if ( cmp( ( const char * )a + max * size, ( const char * )a + i * size ) < 0 )
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    return max;
}   

int cmp_char( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return ( *( const char * )b < *( const char * )a ) -
           ( *( const char * )a < *( const char * )b );
}

int cmp_int( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return ( *( const int * )b < *( const int * )a ) -
           ( *( const int * )a < *( const int * )b );
}

int cmp_double( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return ( *( const double * )b < *( const double * )a ) -
           ( *( const double * )a < *( const double * )b );
}


#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N] = { 0 };
    int a[N];
    double b[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++ )
    {
        s[i] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
    }

    puts( s );

    size_t max = universalMax( s, N - 1, sizeof( char ), cmp_char );

    printf( "The maximum character is %c\n", s[max] );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    max = universalMax( a, N, sizeof( int ), cmp_int );

    printf( "The maximum integer is %d\n", a[max] );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        b[i] = ( double )( rand() % 100 ) / ( rand() % 100 ) ;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%lf ", b[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    max = universalMax( b, N, sizeof( double ), cmp_double );

    printf( "The maximum double is %lf\n", b[max] );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом

```
MLCJRQJKL
The maximum character is R
30 25 -10 -6 45 -36 -48 -46 -15 3 
The maximum integer is 45
0.256410 1.538462 1.534483 2.310345 1.265625 1.430769 0.777778 2.807692 0.304348 1.453125 
The maximum double is 2.807692
```

Answer (score 4):

Написана белиберда в прототипе функции. Правильно

```
size_t universalMax(const void *array, 
                    size_t array_len, size_t size_of_elements, 
                    int (*pcompare)(const void *, const void *));
```

> Но у меня такой вопрос, что такое `void array`?

Бессмыслица. См. выше.

Answer (score 1):

Для массивов примитивных (не структуры) типов такую задачу более эффективно решает следующий макрос

```
#define uMax(array, size) ({__typeof__(*(array)) *_a = array;           \
      __typeof__(_a[0]) _max = _a[0];                                   \
      size_t _imax = 0,                                                 \
        _size = size;                                                   \
      for (size_t i = 1; i < _size; i++)                                \
        if (_a[i] > _max) _max = _a[_imax = i];                         \
      _imax;})
```